# Google API Python script credentials error

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I want to add my CSV file to my Google Drive sheet and I ended up with this script:

```
import gspread
import os.path
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

#scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
#scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
#         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]


#scopes = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
#         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes) #credentials.json?
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

spreadsheet = client.open('Database-TTF')

with open('newTTF-Projects-INFO.csv', 'r') as file_obj:
    content = file_obj.read()
    client.import_csv('1gv-bKe-flo5FwIbt_xgCp1vNn0L0KBnpiuRak9a1efQ', data=content)
```

But unfortunately I got an error:

```
APIError: {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}
```

I was trying to add more scopes (#) use credentials.json or token.json and non of that worked. Do I need maybe to change something in my credentials.json file? I have no idea where is the problem here.
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to update an existing sheet or add a new one to your drive?

Comment: I am trying to add CSV to existing sheet. I know that with this script the old data in sheet will be replaced but that's a good start for me anyway :p

Comment: Then it is pretty straight forward following the [gspread documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html). You need to make sure you share your current spreadsheet with your client_email for the api in the json creds file.